# Installing QuantLib in Anaconda on the Spyder Editor (Windows)

Tags: python, anaconda, quantlib

How do I install the QuantLib Package in Anaconda. I have tried the following code;

```
import QuantLib as ql
```

but I am getting the following result;

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QuantLib'
```

Can anyone assist me

Comment: How did you install the QuantLib package? Where are their docs? What is the proper way to import from their package?

Comment: I tried to install the QuantLib through the Visual Studio but I did not succeed. I have tried almost everything that is on the internet but the installation failed.

Comment: "almost everything on the internet" Well that's quite a lot! Can you be more specific about what you tried most recently? Its impossible to help with such vague details

Comment: I tried what is on this link https://vineetv.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/installing-quantlib-python-windows/

Comment: I tried what is on this link https://vineetv.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/installing-quantlib-python-windows/ where I have to install the QuantLib in Visual Studio and download Boost and SWIG and I did not succeed in the last stage of stage in building the project where there was an error (3>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib'). I created an additional path to the ucrtd folder but it still didn't work. I also followed the video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWMT78XJFJE

Answer (score 7):

You first need to install the QuantLib package. The easiest way I found is to install Anaconda 4.3.1 ([link](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)), open a Command Prompt as Admin and run:

**pip install QuantLib-Python**

For me, this only worked on the latest version of Anaconda including Python 3.6, think the QuantLib-Python package was implemented in PIP only very recently. This might work for other recent installations of Python as well, but it did *not* work for me on older versions of Anaconda or Python 3.5.

Comment: Is it also available for 32 bit installations of Anaconda?

Answer (score 2):

I used this link [download quantlib 1.7.1](https://anaconda.org/tonyroberts/quantlib) to install in Windows 10 (I use Anaconda). It was really smooth and no prob at all.

Comment: Is it also available for 32 bit installations of Anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

`conda install -c conda-forge quantlib` does not appear to quite work while it shows a package in `conda list` as `quantlib`(note the lower case). The pip installation via `python -m pip install QuantLib` from Anaconda prompt did the trick for me and `import QuantLib as ql` runs fine without throwing errors.

see [QuantLib-Python installation on Windows](https://www.quantlib.org/install/windows-python.shtml) for more help.