# QuantLib Error: No module named 'quantlib'

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, quantlib

I have downloaded Anaconda and intend to run Python in Spyder application. I separately downloaded QuantLib package using the code below in Anaconda CMD.

```
conda install -c tonyroberts quantlib
```

Now I can confirm that the package is downloaded as I can see it in the `C:\Users\...\anaconda3\pkgs` folder. Moreover it is also visible in Anaconda Navigator (screenshot for reference):
[Anaconda Navigator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Czqz.png)

When I try to import the library in Spyder using below code:

```
import QuantLib as ql
```

it throws the error-

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QuantLib'
```

Can anybody please help me know where exactly I am making the mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411023/installing-quantlib-in-anaconda-on-the-spyder-editor-windows)  this question may help you

Comment: Thanks @dhananjaysawarkar. I had seen this pip install code but it gave an error in the code "Invalid Syntax  (pyflakes E)" so didn't run it. Now that you sent it again I just tought to try it and it seems to work.